# Компилятор не видит атрибут класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, атрибуты

Писал свой кривой код, добавил свои кривые классы. В классе Window есть атрибут mainWindow.
При попытке дальнейшего использования атрибута компилятор помечает это ошибка c с комментарием:

> NameError: name 'mainWindow' is not defined

Неопятно

```
from time import time
from random import randint
class Application(object):
    class Windows(object):
        mainWindow = Tk()
        mainWindow.title('Guitar Teacher prototype')
        mainWindow.geometry('720x360')

        settingsWindow = Tk()
        settingsWindow.title('Настройки')
        settingsWindow.geometry('720x360')

        applWindow = Tk()
        applWindow.title('Аппликатуры')
        applWindow.geometry('720x360')

    class Buttons(object):
        def __init__(self, text, width, heidth, bg, fg, font):
            self.width = 25
            self.heidth = 5
            self.bg = 'green'
            self.fg = 'white'
            self.font = 'Arial 14'

    #class func(self):
        #def speedChange(spd, speedText):
        #spd = txt.get()
        #return(spd)
    
spd = 2 
accords = ('A', 'C', 'G', 'E', 'D', 'Am', 'Dm', 'Em', 'F', 'A7', 'B7')
mainWindow.
accordLabel = Label(mainWindow, text = '' + accords[randint(0,9)], font = ('Arial, 170'))
```

Answer (score 2):

у тебя `mainWindow` определено в классе Window. Дальше ты пытаешь использовать `mainWindow` без создания объектов класса Window и без предварительного определения, что такое mainWindow поэтому и ругается компилятор